# Assign value to rails_admin list field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, field, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin gem and instead of the actual id field from the database I want to use just a current number, so that the admin won't get to see what the actual id is in my db. So far I tried:

```
# Fields in Projects model
  config.model 'Project' do
    @currentId = 1;
    list do
      field :id do
        @currentId
      end
      field :year
      field :title
      field :intro
      field :description
      field :confidential
      field :star
      field :image
    end
    @currentId += 1;
  end
```

But this displays just my db id. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer]: As long as the db does reset it's id value (e.g: MySql), you can do this:

```
currentId = 0
  # Fields in Projects list
  config.model 'Project' do

    list do
      field :id do
        formatted_value do
          currentId +=1
        end
      end
      field :year
      field :title
      field :intro
      field :description
      field :confidential
      field :star
      field :image
    end
```

If the database keeps incrementing that value, than the current user has to be passed as a binding and the id can be easily tweaked in the main list view of rails_admin

Answer (score 1):

You can do following for this purpose.

1. hide field

   ```
   list do
     configure :id do
        hide
     end

     include_all_fields # all other default fields will be added after, conveniently
   end
   ```
2. exclude field

   ```
   list do
     exclude_fields :id
   end
   ```
3. format field value

   ```
   list do
     field :id do
        formatted_value do # used in form views
          value++
        end
     end

     include_all_fields # all other default fields will be added after, conveniently
   end
   ```

for more configuration visit https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields

Comment: Thanks but it was even easier than this. Please check my answer below!